# Phone booted with an old wallpaper and logged out all my accounts

Tags: boot-loop

So my one plus 9 died to zero and I had to put it on charge. It started bootlooping so pressed the power and volume down to power it off through recovery settings.

When it charged It turned on with any old wallpaper that I have already deleted from my phone, all my accounts were logged out and many permissions revoked. All data is intact tho.

What did I do? And will factory resetting prevent from turning on with said old wallpaper?

Comment: Is it possible that you once had app online backup to GDrive enabled? May be some data got lost and Android recovered the data by restoreing the all data that was still saved in GDrive.

Comment: Factory reset isn't going to help.